# Auto adjust rows according to table to hide/show

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a double toggle button to show and hide certain rows. I have used following vba code to do the same. I am getting stuck at how to provide auto adjusting row no. /Reference so that if I delete or add a row the code auto-adjust row values according to the table I need to hide and show.

***CODE***

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()        
    Dim xAddress As String         
    xAddress = "9:29"

    If ToggleButton1.Value Then 
        Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = True        
        ToggleButton1.Caption = "Show"        
    Else
        Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = False        
        ToggleButton1.Caption = "Hide"        
    End If
End Subs
```

Comment: Either create a named range so you can access these rows with a name (instead of row numbers) or you need to specify how VBA would determine which are the correct rows to hide/show. Please add this information to your question. A screenshot might help too.

Comment: If rows are added/removed it might be a bit tricky - it would help if you also update in your question what data is likely to remain constant over these rows - or even what data might be unique on these rows?